# Kivy/MD - why is my MDLabel in Scrollview showing the last line when it initially displays (w/image and code)?

Tags: kivy, widget, label, scrollview, kivymd

I have a Scrollview with an MDLabel in it.  When I invoke this MDDialog the MDLabel displays but it display the *last page* of text on screen initially.  I want it to display the *first page* of text and then let me scroll down.
In this example, if I click and drag my mouse, I can scroll up, but my mousewheel will not scroll up as it does on other Scrollviews I have.
How do I display the first page of text in MDLabel intially?

[What my scrollview and MDLabel look like - click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rwTu.jpg)

Py - complete run-able minimal code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "400dp"
    markup: True
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "500dp", "700dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 1}
        MDLabel:
            id: MLogfileText
            size_hint: 1,None
            text: "Log file"
            halign: "left"
            text_color: self.theme_cls.primary_light  

"""

class ColorLabelApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        
        screen = Builder.load_string(kv)
        
        screen.ids.MLogfileText.text = (" (first line) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. (last line)")
        
        return screen 

ColorLabelApp().run()
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I posted above the minimal code that can by saved as a .py file and run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the label's height to its texture_size[1] (i.e. height) as,

```py
        MDLabel:
            padding: [20, 20]
            id: MLogfileText
            size_hint: 1,None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
```

Comment: The line `padding: [20, 20]` is optional.

Comment: thats worked perfectly, thanks so much 